# BITWISE AND OR function not working in HIBERNATE 6.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using SQL Server and Spring boot 3.0.2 and HIBERNATE 6.1, and my JPA query look like this.

```
(t1.col1 | t1.col2) = :notIntOnly
```

My custom `SQLServer2012DialectCustom` code

```
@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "(?1 | ?2)",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                "(?1 | ?2)",
                StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER
            )
        );
    
}
```

But I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred []
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.lambda$createQuery$2(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:747)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:744)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.sqm.ParsingException: line 1:146 no viable alternative at input '|'
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator$1.syntaxError(StandardHqlTranslator.java:46)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ProxyErrorListener.syntaxError(ProxyErrorListener.java:41)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.notifyErrorListeners(Parser.java:543)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportNoViableAlternative(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:310)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.DefaultErrorStrategy.reportError(DefaultErrorStrategy.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.queryExpression(HqlParser.java:1180)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.selectStatement(HqlParser.java:382)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser.statement(HqlParser.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.parseHql(StandardHqlTranslator.java:116)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you use to register your "function" doesn't work. You can't register a function under the "name" `(?1 | ?2)`. You have to register a function under an alphanumeric name e.g. `bit_or`

```
@Override
public void contribute(MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder) {
    metadataBuilder.applySqlFunction(
            "bit_or",
            new StandardSQLFunction(
                "(?1 | ?2)",
                StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER
            )
        );
    
}
```

and use it in your query that way:

```
bit_or(t1.col1, t1.col2) = :notIntOnly
```